# Dagger 2 - Right way to pass parameters to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

In my previous projects, I was instantiating my Fragments with Android's build-in method `newInstance(param: Type)` so I wouldn't lose params even Android recreates the Fragment. Now, that I'm migrating to Dagger, legal way to instantiate Fragments is either `@Inject`'ed params or empty constructor (as far as I know). I'm left with two option in my mind which are either to create a custom annotation for each param (cumbersome) or use `@Named`, both looks quite overkill considering 15-20 different purpose Fragments with each requiring 3-4 different `Type` params. I would be happy to hear suggestions or just kinda assertion that those are my only options

Comment: You should still use arguments, or they will be lost when the fragment is recreated. That hasn't changed tbh.

Comment: You mean `Fragment.setArguments(bundle: Bundle)` when I add Fragment to Activity?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant